# Import macro from parent module

Tags: rust, rust-macros, rust-decl-macros

I'm having trouble re-using macros within a crate.

If a macro is defined in `./src/macros.rs`:

```
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! my_macro {
    ...
}
```

and used in `./src/lib.rs`:

```
#[macro_use]
pub mod macros;
```

I can't see this macro in `./src/submod/lib.rs`:

```
my_macro!(...);
```

It yields the error message `error: macro undefined: 'my_macro!'`.

Is there a way I can import this macro in this child module `submod`?

Answer (score 11):

I figured it out! It is imported automatically, but I didn't realize that macros are imported in order!

I imported the `submod` module before `macros`, so `my_macro` wasn't visible *yet*. By swapping the order, I got the expected behaviour.

Comment: It'd be good to see the bit of code that fixed it before and after.

Comment: I also would like to see the code that solved this